# How can I find the Column Line of the current StackFrame in Visual Studio Debugger?

Tags: c#, debugging, vsx, visual-studio-addins, envdte

There is no ColumnNumber property in the EnvDTE.StackFrame2 interface, even though LineNumber does exist: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc701201(v=VS.90).aspx;

IL offset will also do, I could also do the IL offset-> column/line conversion using the pdbs myself.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a way. Breakpoints didn't really have a concept of columns until sometime after C# introduced lambda expressions and even then only C# had the concept until Visual Studio 2010. I don't think they ever released an API to give access to the column

Comment: @JaredPar Thanks. any thinkable hack/workaround that could accomplish the same result? perhaps via a non-debugger API? I'm desperate :/

Comment: one idea is to use the file name and line number to map to a physical line of the file.  Then just say the break point occurs at the first non-white space character of that line.  It will be correct the majority of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I got my answer on [this VS Debugger forum thread.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/d9d7f78a-c1c2-4146-8907-8aeb651da72e/?prof=required)